# How do I make a bootstrap 3 datepicker work in a kendo mvc in-cell batch edit grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

So I can make this work fine in newer browsers, but in IE9 when a date is clicked on the datepicker the cell turns back as unselected, empty and not dirty.
An example of my code is

MODEL

```
public string name { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}", NullDisplayText = "")]
[Display(Name = "Actual Start")]
public DateTime? ActualStartDate { get; set; }

public DateTime? ActualEndDate { get; set; }
```

GRID

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<MilestoneDto>()

     .Name("editMilestoneList")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(m => m.Name).Title("Name");
         columns.Bound(m => m.Status).EditorTemplateName("_milestoneStatus");
         columns.Bound(m => m.PlannedStartDateStringValue);
         columns.Bound(m => m.ProjectedStartDateStringValue);
         columns.Bound(m => m.ActualStartDate).EditorTemplateName("GenericDatePicker");
         columns.Bound(m => m.PlannedEndDateStringValue);
         columns.Bound(m => m.ProjectedEndDateStringValue);
         columns.Bound(m => m.ActualEndDateStringValue).EditorTemplateName("GenericDatePicker");
         columns.Bound(m => m.CommentCount).ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:;' onclick='callCommentModal()'>#if(CommentCount > 0) {# <span class=\"badge\">#=CommentCount#</span>#}else{#<span class=\"fa fa-plus-circle\"></span>#}#</a>").Title("Comments").Sortable(false).IncludeInMenu(false);
     })
     .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hidden results table-responsive" })
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                 .Ajax()
                                 .Read(read => read.Action("DataSource", "Milestone").Data("additionalParams"))
                                 .Update(update => update.Action("BatchEdit", "Milestone"))
                                 .Batch(true)
                                 .Events(e => e.Sync("SyncGrid"))
                                 .ServerOperation(false)
                                 .Model(m => {
                                     m.Id(mf => mf.Id);
                                     m.Field(f => f.Name).Editable(false);
                                     m.Field(f => f.Status).Editable(ViewBag.IsBaselined);
                                     m.Field(f => f.PlannedStartDateStringValue).Editable(false);
                                     m.Field(f => f.PlannedEndDateStringValue).Editable(false);
                                     m.Field(f => f.CommentCount).Editable(false);
                                     m.Field(f => f.ProjectedStartDateStringValue).Editable(false);
                                     m.Field(f => f.ProjectedEndDateStringValue).Editable(false);
                                     m.Field(f => f.ActualStartDate).Editable(ViewBag.IsBaselined);
                                     m.Field(f => f.ActualEndDate).Editable(ViewBag.IsBaselined);                          
                                 })
     )
     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
     .ColumnMenu()
     .Filterable()
     .Sortable();
}
```

EDITOR TEMPLATE

```
@model DateTime? 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { @class="k-textbox bootStrapDatePicker form-   control" })
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.bootStrapDatePicker').datepicker({ startDate: '0', format: "m/d/yyyy", autoclose:   true });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two (better) options that will automatically set up the DateTimePicker for you:

1) In the grid columns/models, use your `ActualStartDate` properties. Then you can use the `.Format()` method on your columns to format it how you'd like.

2) I don't know what the exact syntax is, but when you're defining the `Model` in the Grid, I I believe there is a `DataType()` or similar method to set it as a date time.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but it turns out the problems was the version of jquery was incorrect.